# I need help with using composite simpsons rule to solve an improper integral

Tags: numerical-methods

I need help using Composite Simpson's rule to solve this improper integral:
 $$\displaystyle \int_0^2 \dfrac{xe^x}{(x-1)^{2/3}}\,dx$$

We have to use $n=2$ for this question.

Comment: I'm confused with the denominator of the integrand. Do you intend $\int_0^2 \frac{xe^x}{3\sqrt{(x-1)^2}}\,dx$ ?

Comment: yes that is what i meant to write, sorry

Comment: the second one is what i meant.

Comment: yes it is correct, could you help solve please?